# Even without reading a package option the code defined in it is read in the compilation. What is the problem in the codes?

Tags: graphics, packages, conditionals, package-writing, package-options

**The problem!**

My tex file is
...

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{scrbook}
%%%
\usepackage[capimage]{suave}
%%%
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapterimage{imagetest}    
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapterimage{imagetest}    
\chapter{Rings and Fields}
A ring is a set on which addition, subtraction, multiplication. A field is a comutative ring wiht  division. 

\section{The life}
The life likes those who likes she.
\end{document}
```

...

This file compiles without problems, but if the line

```
             `\usepackage[capimage]{suave}` is replaced by `\usepackage{suave}`
```

and the command

```
                     `\chapterimage{imagetest}`
```

is commented before \tableofcontents and \chapter in the tex file, compilation still fails and the following error message appears

```
 Too many }'s. ...age\renewcommand{\thechapterimage}{#1}\fi}
 Extra \fi. \begin
 Environment tikzpicture undefined. \tableofcontents
 Undefined control sequence. \tableofcontents
```

This is strange because the "capimage" option of the suave package was not loaded, so the code defined in it should not be read, much less present an error because we verified that the code is correct.

**What's wrong with this code?**

I appreciate any comments.

The suave.sty file is

```
%%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{suave}[2016/11/11 v1. Pacote de facilidades]
%%%
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=5pt}
%%%
\newif\if@loadcapimage
\DeclareOption{capimage}{\@loadcapimagetrue}
%%%
\ProcessOptions\relax 
%%%
%%% Option capimage
%%%
\if@loadcapimage
%%%
\RequirePackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{laranja}{RGB}{243,102,25}%%%{0,128,128}
    \newcommand{\laranja}[1]{{\color{laranja}#1}}
\RequirePackage{tikz,pgf}          
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}    
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
    \usetikzlibrary{shadows}
    \newcommand{\separador}{:}
\makeatletter
% A switch to conditionally include a picture, implemented by  Christian Hupfer
\newif\ifusechapterimage
\usechapterimagetrue
\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}%
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[1]{\ifusechapterimage\renewcommand{\thechapterimage}{#1}\fi}%
%%%\newcommand{\autodot}{.} %%% Defined in scrbook class or other package in the komascript.
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=laranja,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}\chaptername\,\thechapter\separador\autodot~#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\else
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=laranja,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\fi\fi\par\vspace*{270\p@}}}

%-------------------------------------------

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=laranja,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\vspace*{270\p@}}
\makeatother
\fi 
%%% 
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm} %%% 
%%%
\endinput
```

Comment: you can not have a `\newif` definition inside an `\if...` block, move it outside

Comment: also do not use `\makeatletter/\makeatother` in package files

Comment: Thank you very much, David.

I moved \ newif out of the \ if ... block and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
\if@loadcapimage
%%%
\RequirePackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{laranja}{RGB}{243,102,25}%%%{0,128,128}
    \newcommand{\laranja}[1]{{\color{laranja}#1}}
\RequirePackage{tikz,pgf}          
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}    
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
    \usetikzlibrary{shadows}
    \newcommand{\separador}{:}
\makeatletter
% A switch to conditionally include a picture, implemented by  Christian Hupfer
\newif\ifusechapterimage
\usechapterimagetrue
\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}%
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[1]{\ifusechapterimage\renewcommand{\thechapterimage}{#1}\fi}
```

So in the case that `\if@loadcapimage` is false,  all this code is skipped but scanning for the matching `\fi` to end the block.

As this is being skipped `\newif` does *not* expand and so `\ifusechapterimage` is not defined to an `\if` token (or anything) and so the  `\fi`  at  the end of the line shown does not match the intended `\ifusechapterimage` but matches `\if@loadcapimage` and so the outer block skipping ends and everything goes wrong.

Move the  `\newif` line  earlier so that the `\ifusechapterimage` is seen as an if token and correctly matched while scanning this section.

unrelated but you should also delete `\makeatletter` as `@` is automatically a letter in package files.

Comment: David! It is working very well, your comments were accurate and enlightening. Thank you very much